# Question about the long run behaviour of MC

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, transition-matrix

I have the following exercise and I have some doubts about it's solution.

[image]

a) Find $P\{X_4=1\}$.

b) Calculate the limiting distribution.

c) What is the long run rate of repairs per unit time?

My attempt:

For a) I think first I need to establish the transition matrix, but I'm not sure if this way is correct:

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        .9 & .1 & 0 \\
        0 & .9 & .1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
I think it's not correct because they're asking me for $P\{X_4=1\}$ so the matrix needs the fourth entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state space of the given Markov chain has three states $$S=\{1:\text{Good Operating Order, 2:Deteriorated Operating Order, 3:In Repair}\}.$$ 
$X_{n}$ denotes the state that the Markov chain occupies at time $n$. The probabilities that the chain can be found in different states at time $n$ is specified using a row vector, denoted by $p^{(n)}$. It is also called the state probability vector at time $n$. By definition, then
$$p^{(n)}=(P\{X_{n}=1\},P\{X_{n}=2\},P\{X_{n}=3\}).$$
For example, $p^{(2)}=(0.2,0.5,0.3)$ means that the process could be found in state-1 with probability $0.2$, in state-2 with probability $0.5$ and in state-3 with probability $0.3$ at time $n=2$.

To study a Markov chain, what all we require is, a transition probability matrix $P$ , and the initial probability distribution of the chain. The initial probability distribution, by convention, is defined by a row vector. By initial probability distribution of the chain we mean with what probability the chain could start in different states of the chain at time $n=0$. In other words, it is the vector $$(P\{X_{0}=1\},P\{X_{0}=2\},P\{X_{0}=3\})$$

We are given  that $X_{0}=1$, which means that the  process starts in state-1. This in turn means that the   initial probability distribution of the chain is $p^{(0)}=(1,0,0)$. By pre-multiplying the $P$ with $p^{(0)}$, we get the state probability vector at time 1. That is, $p^{(1)}=p^{(0)}P$. Similarly, $p^{(2)}=p^{(1)}P=(p^{(0)}P)P=p^{(0)}P^{(2)}$, where $P^{(2)}$ is the two-step transition probability matrix. In general, $$p^{(n)}=p^{(0)}P^{(n)}.$$ So, to calculate the state probabilities at time $n$, we require the initial probability vector and the n-step transition probability matrix.

To answer (a), compute $P^{(4)}$ and pre-multiply it by $p^{(0)}$ and pick up the first element of that vector, since you are interested in with what probability that the process will be found in state-1.

Comment: how did you compute $p^{(2)}$ =(.2,.5,.3)? (apologize for my ignorance)

Comment: It is just an example I have chosen to interpret the meaning of the components of state probability vector.

Comment: :D Oh I see, and what's $P$ (I know it's the transition matrix) but specifically?

Comment: P is your transition probability matrix. Computing $p^{(1)}:$
\begin{eqnarray*}
p^{(1)}&=&p^{(0)}P = (1,0,0)\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0.9&0.1&0\\
0&0.9&0.1\\
1.0&0&0
\end{array}\right) = (0.9,  0.1,    0)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I compute $p^{(0)}$ $P^4$ and the first element of the vector is .6561 but the answer of the book is .6831 .Why is that?

Comment: Check your $P^{(4)}$.

Comment: Mathematica did it

Comment: $P^{(2)}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0.81& 0.18& 0.01\\
0.10& 0.81& 0.09\\
0.90& 0.10& 0.00
\end{array}\right)$


$P^{(4)}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
 0.6831& 0.2926& 0.0243\\
 0.2430& 0.6831& 0.0739\\
 0.7390& 0.2430& 0.0180\\
\end{array}\right)$

Comment: the (4) is an exponential right? like p^2 is p*p

Comment: $P^{(4)}=P\cdot P\cdot P\cdot P$. I don't know mathematica. My output is from R.

Comment: oh ok, so the process is correct, the problem is mathematica :(

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you've simply written down a transition matrix by reflex, but haven't grokked what it *means*:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
P(X_{n+1} = 1)
& P(X_{n+1} = 2)
& P(X_{n+1} = 3)
\end{pmatrix} 
=
\begin{pmatrix}
P(X_{n} = 1)
& P(X_{n} = 2)
& P(X_{n} = 3)
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
        .9 & .1 & 0 \\
        0 & .9 & .1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Where, I assume, $P_{ij}$ means the probability of a machine in state $i$ transitioning to state $j$.

Comment: And what's P{$X_4$=1} then?..The problem is I've been working with just "simple" transition matrix or easy matrix, and the above one is affected by (P{$X_n$=1 }P{$X_n$=1} P{$X_n$=3})  .So I don't know what to do :(

Comment: So figure out what $P(X_3 = i)$ is first. Or use your linear algebra to simplify the whole thing: $v_{n+1} = v_n A$. One you know how to find $v_4$, *then* you do the numeric calculation.

Comment: P($X_3$=i) is the probability of being in state i at time 3. right?

Comment: I don't know why I don't understand you ** :( **